# using haskell pipes-bytestring to iterate a file by line

Tags: haskell-pipes

I am using the pipes library and need to convert a ByteString stream to a stream of lines (i.e. `String`), using ASCII encoding. I am aware that there are other libraries (Pipes.Text and Pipes.Prelude) that perhaps let me yield lines from a text file more easily, but because of some other code I need to be able to get lines as `String` from a Producer of `ByteString`.

More formally, I need to convert a `Producer ByteString IO ()` to a `Producer String IO ()`, which yields lines.

I am sure this must be a one-liner for an experienced Pipes-Programmer, but I so far did not manage to successfully hack through all the `FreeT` and `Lens`-trickery in Pipes-ByteString.

Any help is much appreciated!

Stephan

Comment: `lined :: Monad m => Producer ByteString m r -> Producer String m (Producer ByteString m r)` `lined  = folds mappend mempty T.unpack . view PT.lines . PTE.decodeAscii`. If you want to delete possible unreadable bytestring leftover, add `Control.Monad.void` .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you need that type signature, then I would suggest this:

```
import Control.Foldl (mconcat, purely)
import Data.ByteString (ByteString)
import Data.Text (unpack)
import Lens.Family (view)
import Pipes (Producer, (>->))
import Pipes.Group (folds)
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as Pipes
import Pipes.Text (lines)
import Pipes.Text.Encoding (utf8)
import Prelude hiding (lines)

getLines
    :: Producer ByteString IO r -> Producer String IO (Producer ByteString IO r)
getLines p = purely folds mconcat (view (utf8 . lines) p) >-> Pipes.map unpack
```

This works because the type of `purely folds mconcat` is:

```
purely folds mconcat
    :: (Monad m, Monoid t) => FreeT (Producer t m) r -> Producer t m r
```

... where `t` in this case would be `Text`:

```
purely folds mconcat
    :: Monad m => FreeT (Producer Text m) r -> Producer Text m r
```

Any time you want to reduce each `Producer` sub-group of a `FreeT`-delimited stream you probably want to use `purely folds`.  Then it's just a matter of picking the right `Fold` to reduce the sub-group with.  In this case, you just want to concatenate all the `Text` chunks within a group, so you pass in `mconcat`.  I generally don't recommend doing this since it will break on extremely long lines, but you specified that you needed this behavior.

The reason this is verbose is because the `pipes` ecosystem promotes `Text` over `String` and also tries to encourage handling arbitrarily long lines.  If you were not constrained by your other code then the more idiomatic approach would just be:

```
view (utf8 . lines)
```

Comment: Great answer, Thanks! Also helpful for understanding the lenses in this library.

Answer (score 1):

After a little bit of hacking and some hints from this [blog](http://snak.tumblr.com), I came up with a solution, but it is surprisingly clumsy, and I fear a bit inefficient as well, as it uses ByteString.append:

```
import Pipes
import qualified Pipes.ByteString as PB
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as PP
import qualified Pipes.Group as PG
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as B
import Lens.Family (view )
import Control.Monad (liftM)

getLines :: Producer PB.ByteString IO r -> Producer String IO r
getLines = PG.concats . PG.maps toStringProducer . view PB.lines

toStringProducer :: Producer PB.ByteString IO r -> Producer String IO r
toStringProducer producer = go producer B.empty
  where
    go producer bs = do
        x <- lift $ next producer
        case x of
            Left r -> do
                yield $ B.unpack bs
                return r
            Right (bs', producer') -> go producer' (B.append bs' bs)
```