# haskell pipes - how to repeatedly perform a takeWhile operation on a bytestring pipe?

Tags: haskell, streaming, haskell-pipes

What I'm trying to do is use takeWhile to split a bytestring by some character.

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Internal as BS (c2w, w2c)
import Pipes
import Pipes.ByteString as PB
import Pipes.GZip
import Pipes.Prelude as PP
import System.IO

newline = BS.c2w '\n'

splitter = PB.takeWhile (\myWord -> myWord /= newline)

myPipe fileHandle = PP.toListM $ decompress fileProducer >-> splitter
  where
    fileProducer = PB.fromHandle fileHandle       

run = do
  dat <- withFile "somefile.blob" ReadMode myPipe
  pure dat
```

This gets me the first line, but what I really want is to effectively yield each chunk up to a newline character at a time. How do I do that?

Comment: Here's a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25982213/using-haskell-pipes-bytestring-to-iterate-a-file-by-line/27727521#27727521

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pipes-bytestring` and `pipes-group` are arranged so that repeatedly breaking a `Producer ByteString m r` yields a `FreeT (Producer ByteString m) m r`. `FreeT` can here be read to mean `A_Succession_Of`, so the result can be thought of as 'a succession of bytestring-producer segments returning an r'. This way if one of the segments is, say, 10 gibabytes long, [we still have streaming rather than a 10 gigabyte strict bytestring](http://www.haskellforall.com/2013/09/perfect-streaming-using-pipes-bytestring.html).

It looks to me that you want to break the bytestring producer on newlines, but I couldn't tell if you wanted to keep the newlines. If you are throwing them out, this is the same as splitting the bytestring producer with `view PB.lines`, followed by concatenating each subordinate producer into a single strict bytestring - the individual line. I wrote this below as `accumLines`. It is straightforward, but makes a tiny use of `Lens.view` to turn the fancy `PB.lines` lens into a regular function. (Many operations are written as lenses in `pipes-bytestring` because then they can be re-used for other purpose, especially the kind of producer parsing `pipes` favors.)

```
import Pipes
import qualified Pipes.Prelude as P
import Pipes.ByteString as PB
import qualified Pipes.Group as PG
import Pipes.GZip

import qualified Data.ByteString.Internal as BS (c2w, w2c)

import System.IO
import Lens.Simple (view) -- or Control.Lens or whatever
import Data.Monoid

main = run >>= mapM_ print

myPipe fileHandle = P.toListM $ accumLines (decompress fileProducer)
  where
    fileProducer = PB.fromHandle fileHandle

run = do
  dat <- withFile "a.gz" ReadMode myPipe
  pure dat

-- little library additions

accumLines :: Monad m => Producer ByteString m r -> Producer ByteString m r
accumLines = mconcats . view PB.lines 

accumSplits :: Monad m => Char -> Producer ByteString m r -> Producer ByteString m r
accumSplits c  = mconcats . view (PB.splits (BS.c2w c)) 

-- this is convenient, but the operations above could 
-- be more rationally implemented using e.g. BL.fromChunks and toListM 
mconcats :: (Monad m, Monoid b) => FreeT (Producer b m) m r -> Producer b m r
mconcats = PG.folds (<>) mempty id
```

Ideally you would not write a new bytestring at each line break. Whether you have to depends on what you were going to do with the lines.

Comment: Is `PG.concats` is the same as your `mconcats` ?

Comment: No, `PG.concats` just removes the `FreeT` breaks in the succession, so it doesn't have a monoid constraint. The analogy to `concat` follows the general analogy `FreeT (Producer m) m r  : Producer a m r  ::  [[a]] : [a]`  My little `mconcats` crushes each successive producer of monoidal values into a summary monoidal value - that is, it does a number of little mconcat-like operations. Maybe it's not the best name.

Comment: i'm running every n lines in a parser (probably attoparsec or megaparsec) to build records. it would seem like i would have to build individual bytestrings (at least one per record for that). or is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: If you have written a single attoparsec parser that succeeds on a given n-line segment and returns a record, then you can repeatedly apply it directly to the bytestring producer, without breaking it into lines.  See [`Pipes.Attoparsec.decoded`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/pipes-attoparsec-0.5.1.3/docs/Pipes-Attoparsec.html#v:parsed). So, `parsed my_n_line_parser . decompress` will stream the records as they come from the compressed file; if it fails it will return the rest of the (decompressed) producer of bytestrings with messages. If it fits the task this may be simplest.

Answer (score 3):

@Michael's answer is good. I just want to illustrate some
usage patterns that are going on here.

( .lhs available at http://lpaste.net/165352 )

First a few imports:

```
 {-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings, NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}

 import Pipes
 import qualified Pipes.Prelude as PP
 import qualified Pipes.Group as PG
 import qualified Pipes.ByteString as PB
 import qualified Pipes.GZip as GZip
 import qualified Data.ByteString as BS
 import Lens.Family (view, over)
 import Control.Monad
 import System.IO
```

If you look over the functions in Pipes.ByteString and Pipes.GZip
you'll see that they all into the following type schemas:

1. Producer ... -> FreeT (Producer ...) ...
2. FreeT (Producer ...) ...  -> Producer ...
3. Lens' (Producer ...) (FreeT (Producer ...) ...)
4. Producer ... -> Producer ...

Examples of functions in each category:

1. `PB.words`
2. `PG.concats`
3. `PB.lines`, `PB.chunksOf`, `PB.splits`, ...
4. `GZip.compress`, `GZip.decompress`

Here's how to use `PB.words` to split an input stream into words:

```
 prod = yield "this is\na test\nof the pipes\nprocessing\nsystem"

 t1 = runEffect $ (PG.concats . PB.words) prod >-> PP.print
```

To use a function of type 3 -- e.g. `PB.lines`, just use `view` on the
`Lens'` to get a function of type 1 and then compose with `PG.concats`:

```
 t2a = runEffect $ (PG.concats . view PB.lines) prod >-> PP.print

 t2b h = (PG.concats . view PB.lines) (PB.fromHandle h) >-> PP.print

 run2 = withFile "input" ReadMode (runEffect . t2b)
```

For a Producer -> Producer function, just use normal function application:

```
 t3 h = GZip.decompress (PB.fromHandle h) >-> PP.print

 run3 = withFile "input.gz" ReadMode (runEffect . t3)

 t4 h = GZip.decompress (PB.fromHandle h) >-> PP.map BS.length >-> PP.print

 run4 = withFile "big.gz" ReadMode (runEffect . t4)
```

To first decompress and then split by lines, we nest function
application:

```
 t5 h = (PG.concats . view PB.lines) ( GZip.decompress (PB.fromHandle h) )
          >-> PP.map BS.length >-> PP.print

 run5 = withFile "input.gz" ReadMode (runEffect . t5)
```

Comment: Thanks for explaining this. Why is some functionality provided as a lens view vs. providing transformation functions directly? I understand lenses provide more generality, but the design is not obvious beyond that. What does it mean that the lenses are described as "improper" in the haddocks?

Comment: Those are good questions for http://stackoverflow.com/users/1026598/gabriel-gonzalez ! Another place to ask questions specifically about pipes is the [pipes mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/haskell-pipes)